# Transpose rows to column without numbers to aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have login credentials along with the status and URL some have multiple userids and some have one only I want to group them by employee id and transpose the data. How can I do it in SQL Server 2019?

Database:

```
empid name  desc uid loc status url
100   Smith AA   U1  CA  O      www
100   Smith AA   U2  CA  C      www
100   Smith BB   U3  CA  C      www
100   Smith CC   U4  NY  C      www
101   Adams BB   U5  CA  C      www
101   Adams CC   U6  NY  C      www
```

Desired Results

```
emid name  AA loc sta url BB Loc sta url CC loc url
100  Smith U1 CA  O   www U3 CA  C   www U4  NY www
100  Smith U2 CA  C   www
101  Adams                U5 CA  C   www U6 NY www
```

Comment: And what have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @DaleK I tried to search online similar logic but no luck…

Comment: If you provide your sample data as DDL+DML you make it much easier for people to assist.

Comment: Is [desc] truly limited to AA, BB and CC?  If not you may be looking for a Dynamic PIVOT or even a Conditional Aggregation.

Comment: It could be more than that.

Comment: How many more than that?

Comment: Seems you want a dynamic pivot; there are *alot* of examples out there for those.

Comment: Hi @DaleK it could be 30-50 but if not in used it will not be there just yet.

Comment: And I assume you can have multiple of any of AA, BB, CC per empid? This is a problem that is tricky to solve in SQL, in fact SQL is usually not the best place to solve it. Your front end application is a much better place to solve it.

Comment: Is there anyway to do it in vb.net but the raw data is coming from the sql server then display the result in datagridview?

Comment: The presentation layer would be the best place, @James , but that's not the question you've asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a dynamic solution:

```sql
SELECT  *
INTO #data
FROM    (
    VALUES  (100, N'Smith', N'AA', N'U1', N'CA', N'O', N'www')
    ,   (100, N'Smith', N'AA', N'U2', N'CA', N'C', N'www')
    ,   (100, N'Smith', N'BB', N'U3', N'CA', N'C', N'www')
    ,   (100, N'Smith', N'CC', N'U4', N'NY', N'C', N'www')
    ,   (101, N'Adams', N'BB', N'U5', N'CA', N'C', N'www')
    ,   (101, N'Adams', N'CC', N'U6', N'NY', N'C', N'www')
) t (empid,name,[desc],uid,loc,status,url)


DECLARE @table NVARCHAR(667) = '#data'
,   @ids nvarchar(max) = '[empid], [name]'
,   @group_field sysname = '[desc]'

DECLARE @fields TABLE (pv sysname, label sysname, sort int)

INSERT INTO @fields
VALUES  ('uid', '@@group@@', 1)
,   ('loc', 'loc', 2)
,   ('status', 'sta', 3)
,   ('url', 'url', 4)

-- Build groups...
CREATE TABLE #t_groups (grp nvarchar(max) COLLATE database_default)

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
insert into #t_groups
select distinct ' + @group_field + '
from ' + @table

EXEC    sp_executesql @sql

-- build the final sql
SET @sql = '
    select ' + @ids + ', ' 

SELECT  @sql = @sql + STRING_AGG(CONCAT('max(case when ' , @group_field,'= ',quotename(grp, ''''), ' then ', QUOTENAME(f.pv), ' end', ') as ', REPLACE(f.label, '@@group@@', QUOTENAME(t.grp))), ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY t.grp, f.sort)
FROM    #t_groups t
CROSS JOIN @fields f

/*
-- Older version without string_agg:

SELECT  @sql = @sql + STUFF(
    (
    SELECT CONCAT(',max(case when ' , @group_field,'= ',quotename(grp, ''''), ' then ', QUOTENAME(f.pv), ' end', ') as ', REPLACE(f.label, '@@group@@', QUOTENAME(t.grp)))
    FROM    #t_groups t
    CROSS JOIN @fields f
    ORDER BY t.grp, f.sort
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
*/ 
SET @sql = @sql + '
from (
    select *
    , row_number() over(partition by ' + @ids + ',' + @group_field + 'order by @@spid) as sort
    from ' + @table + '
    ) t
group by ' + @ids + ', sort'

--SELECT    @sql

EXEC    (@sql)
```

I created some variables that holds the information you want to group by etc.

`@ids` contains list of columns that should identify a unique row
`@group_field` is the pivoting field that controls how the columns are pivoted

`@fields` are the pivoted fields table which maps the fields to a label.

For dynamic pivots one needs to get a list of groups, which i do by populating the `#t_groups` table. Then, the rest of the code builds the whole thing together and finally executes the dynamic string. You can use print to figure out the final string.

Output is:

| empid | name | AA | loc | sta | url | BB | loc | sta | url | CC | loc | sta | url |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Smith | U1 | CA | O | www | U3 | CA | C | www | U4 | NY | C | www |
| 100 | Smith | U2 | CA | C | www | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 101 | Adams | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | U5 | CA | C | www | U6 | NY | C | www |

Comment: I will try it. I will let you know if I would be able to follow. Thank you, really appreciate it.

Comment: Just tried I am getting ‘STRING_AGG’ is not a recognized built-in function name. I am using MSSMS 2019. It turns out the SELECT @@VERSION it’s Microsoft SQL Server 2016.

Comment: string_agg is only available in sql server 2017. You should post correct tags!

Comment: Added an alternative version in comments for those with older version

Comment: It works. I will cross check with my actual data. Thank you. You’re the best.

Comment: When I run the script again I am getting this error there is an object named #data in the database. How can I delete and execute it?

Comment: hmm. the script creates some test tables in the beginning, so you can just use drop table #data; drop table #t_groups. To be honest, this is a bit too basic questions, so i'm getting worried, perhaps you shouldn't use dynamic pivots just yet, since it's a quite a bit of advanced feature

Comment: `drop table #data` or just skip that part. Ultimate you need to replace that logic to retrieve the data from your own sources.

Comment: Hi @siggemannen I tried it with my actual columns it looks like different output can you fix it? Here’s my fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/wfDsElmy

Comment: It's because fields and ids have same fields. It makes no sense, because fields are the ones that are pivoted. and you can't pivot the IDs. also, your expected data is not correct, because kim young doesn't have a perth account. Check this fiddle anyway for a "fixed" version of your data: https://dbfiddle.uk/jr9otLzN

Comment: Thank you so much. Really appreciate it.